# My flask-socketio website is working fine on http but not on https on google cloud compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using

```
socket= io.connect();
```

for client and

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
sio = SocketIO(app)
```

for the server.

I have used all (*.crt and *.key are generated via openssl)
entrypoint:

```
gunicorn -b :8080 -k eventlet main:app
gunicorn --certfile=certificate.crt --keyfile=privateKey.key -b :443 -k eventlet main:app 
gunicorn --certfile=certificate.crt --keyfile=privateKey.key -b :8080 -k eventlet main:app
```

Any idea to resolve the issue?
As I mentioned I tried the site works fine on http domain that google cloud provides but not on the https site one.

Comment: What is the error/what behavior are you receiving when trying to access https version?

Comment: When I use  gunicorn -b :8080 -k eventlet main:app then http site at XXX.appspot.com works fine but at https site at XXX.ue.r.appspot.com the client does not communicate with the server. When I use gunicorn --certfile=certificate.crt --keyfile=privateKey.key -b :443 -k eventlet main:app

gunicorn --certfile=certificate.crt --keyfile=privateKey.key -b :8080 -k eventlet main:app

Comment: When I use  gunicorn -b :8080 -k eventlet main:app then http site at XXX.appspot.com works fine but at https site at XXX.ue.r.appspot.com the client does not communicate with the server. When I use gunicorn --certfile=certificate.crt --keyfile=privateKey.key -b :443 -k eventlet main:app

gunicorn --certfile=certificate.crt --keyfile=privateKey.key -b :8080 -k eventlet main:app then both http and https says waiting for website XXX.ue.r.appspot.com ... and it takes forever with no response (sometime it gives timeout error)

Comment: Can you please verify which GCP product you are using? If it's Compute Engine please share your firewall config.